# Full specialisation of a class template using a C++20 concept of a non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-specialization, c++-concepts

I am fairly new to C++20 Concepts and I am experimenting with creating a template class `Foo` with fully specialised implementations based on a non-type (enumerator) template parameter. I have tested my idea using the code below:

```
// Foo.h
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Type { A, B, C };

template<std::is_enum T1, std::is_enum T2>
constexpr bool isEnumSame() { return T1 == T2; }

template<Type T> concept isTypeA = isEnumSame<T, Type::A>;
template<Type T> concept isTypeB = isEnumSame<T, Type::B>;

template<Type T>
struct Foo
{
   Foo() { std::cout << "Generic Foo\n"; }
};

template<Type T>
requires isTypeA<T>
struct Foo<T>
{
   Foo() { std::cout << "Type A Foo\n"; }
};

template<Type T>
requires isTypeB<T>
struct Foo<T>
{
   Foo() { std::cout << "Type B Foo\n"; }
};
```

```
// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"

int main(void)
{
   Foo<Type::C> testC;
   Foo<Type::A> testA;
   Foo<Type::B> testB;

   return 0;
}
```

However, I get compiler errors like the following (I'm using g++11 and gcc11):

```
error: insufficient contextual information to determine type
   27 |       Foo<Type::C> testC;
```

and similarly for `Foo<Type::A> testA` and `Foo<Type::B> testB`. Can someone advise me on what I may be doing incorrectly here? Also, I would ideally like to define the full specialisations similar to:

```
template<isTypeA T>
struct Foo<T>
{
   Foo() { Print("Type A Foo"); }
};
```

but the above yields the compiler error `error: ‘isTypeA’ does not constrain a type`. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `std::is_enum` is not a concept

Answer (score 2):

`std::is_enum` is not a concept, so this predicate does not do what I assume you think it does:

```
template<std::is_enum T1, std::is_enum T2>
constexpr bool isEnumSame() { return T1 == T2; }
```

You can take `Type` values directly. Also, your concept lines need to call the functions like so:

```
template<Type T1, Type T2>
constexpr bool isEnumSame() { return T1 == T2; }

template<Type T> concept isTypeA = isEnumSame<T, Type::A>();
template<Type T> concept isTypeB = isEnumSame<T, Type::B>();
```

If you want your `isEnumSame` to be generic over any enumeration:

```
template <class T>
concept Enumeration = std::is_enum_v<T>;

template<Enumeration auto T1, Enumeration auto T2>
constexpr bool isEnumSame() { return T1 == T2; }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems:

1. ```
   template<std::is_enum T1, std::is_enum T2>
   ```

   `is_enum` is a trait, not a concept. You can use something like `auto T1`, and then  `requires std::is_enum_v<decltype(T1)>`.
2. ```
   template<Type T> concept isTypeA = isEnumSame<T, Type::A>;`
   ```

   You forgot to call the function, add `()`.

---

But you don't actually need any of this concept magic. You can fully specialize `Foo` for the enum values:

```
template <>
struct Foo<Type::A> {...};
```

If you for some reason don't want a full specialization, you can do this:

```
template <Type T>
requires (T == Type::A)
struct Foo<T> {...};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing these out! The reason I decided to go with concepts is that in my actual implementation, I want to specialise the class template based on groups of enumerator types :)

Comment: Regarding the last part of my post, do you know if it Is possible to define the specialisation as `
template<isTypeA T> struct Foo<T>
{
   Foo() { Print("Type A Foo"); }
}; ` instead of with the requires clause? I currently get the error: `error: ‘isTypeA’ does not constrain a type`.

Comment: @niran90 I think it's only possible for type parameters, and yours is not.

Answer (score 1):

First, `std::is_enum` is *not* a concept, it is just a normal class,
so a syntax like `template<std::is_enum T1, std::is_enum T2>` just defines a template function that accepts a non-type template parameter of type `std::is_enum`, which is not what you might expect and doesn't constrain anything.

Second, the template parameter of `bool isEnumSame()` is *not* a type but a enum value, so it should be defined as `template<auto T1, auto T2>`.

If you need to constrain the type of the non-type template parameter, you can just use `decltype` to get its type and use *requires*-expression to constrain it, like this:

```
enum class Type { A, B, C };

template<auto T1, auto T2>
  requires std::is_enum_v<decltype(T1)> && std::is_enum_v<decltype(T2)>
constexpr bool isEnumSame() { return T1 == T2; }

template<Type T> concept isTypeA = isEnumSame<T, Type::A>();
template<Type T> concept isTypeB = isEnumSame<T, Type::B>();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/faevej53n)

Comment: Thanks! This clarified a lot for me :)

Comment: There is such syntax as `template<std::is_enum T>`: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PEWxh3z4G).

Comment: @Barry Agreed, it is syntactically correct (I have just also verified), but it yields different behaviour to the above.