# Specialise Member Function If Type Satisifies Concept

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider a struct which has a member function which needs to have a different implementation for types which satisfy some concept. I attempted to implemented the struct as follows:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept CanDouble = requires (T a) {
    a + a;
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    T Load() {
        return m_bar;
    }

    T m_bar;
};

template<typename T> requires CanDouble<T>
T Foo<T>::Load() {
    return m_bar + m_bar;
}
```

However, this does not compile (type constraint differs in template redeclaration). What is the correct way to implement this functionality?

This earlier question ([Full specialisation of a class template using a C++20 concept of a non-type template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71318446/full-specialisation-of-a-class-template-using-a-c20-concept-of-a-non-type-temp)) seems to want something similar, however that specialises the entire class (not just the member function).

Comment: These are two different unrelated templates, not a template and its specialization. There are no partial function template specializations in C++ to begin with. You want both declared as members of `Foo`: `template <class T> struct Foo { T Load(); T Load() requires CanDouble<T>; ...}`

Comment: Yeah, I was working off the incorrect assumption that it would work in the same way as specialisation for a single type. (`template<> float Foo<float>::Load()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specialize the member function with `if constexpr`

```
T Load() {
  if constexpr (CanDouble<T>)
    return m_bar + m_bar;
  else
    return m_bar;
}
```

Or provide a constrained overload that is instantiated when the concept is satisfied

```
T Load() {
  return m_bar;
}

T Load() requires CanDouble<T> {
  return m_bar + m_bar;
}
```